# Porting Javascript IMEI validator to Java

Tags: java, javascript

I'm trying to port some Javascript code to Java. I have successfully ported the code, but it is not valid - every time it fails at the last number.

Link to check validation: http://imei-number.com/imei-validation-check/

Here is my Javascript code:

```
function imei_gen() {
    var pos;
    var str = new Array(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0);
    var sum = 0;
    var final_digit = 0;
    var t = 0;
    var len_offset = 0;
    var len = 15;
    var issuer;
    var rbi = ["01", "10", "30", "33", "35", "44", "45", "49", "50", "51", "52", "53", "54", "86", "91", "98", "99"];
    var arr = rbi[Math.floor(Math.random() * rbi.length)].split("");
    str[0] = Number(arr[0]);
    str[1] = Number(arr[1]);
    pos = 2;
    while (pos < len - 1) {
        str[pos++] = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10);
    }
    len_offset = (len + 1) % 2;
    for (pos = 0; pos < len - 1; pos++) {
        if ((pos + len_offset) % 2) {
            t = str[pos] * 2;
            if (t > 9) {
                t -= 9;
            }
            sum += t;
        } else {
            sum += str[pos];
        }
    }
    final_digit = (10 - (sum));
    str[len - 1] = final_digit;
    t = str.join('');
    t = t.substr(0, len);
    return t;
}
print(imei_gen());
```

I have used ScriptEngine, but it is taking too much time, almost 2 seconds to complete.

Here is the implementation:

```
import java.io.FileReader;

import javax.script.ScriptEngine;
import javax.script.ScriptEngineManager;

public class SriptEngineJava {
public static void main(String args[]){
     ScriptEngineManager manager = new ScriptEngineManager();
        ScriptEngine engine = manager.getEngineByName("js");
        try {
          FileReader reader = new FileReader("imei.js");
          engine.eval(reader);
          //reader.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
          e.printStackTrace();
        }
}
}
```

And finally the Java implementation:

```
public class Imei {

        public static void main(String[] args) {
            Imei.imei_gen();
        }
        public static void imei_gen(){
             int pos;
                int str[] = {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0};
                int sum = 0;
                int final_digit = 0;
                int t = 0;
                int len_offset = 0;
                int len = 15;
                int issuer;
                String rbi[] = {"01","10","30","33","35","44","45","49","50","51","52","53","54","86","91","98","99"};
                String arr[] = rbi[(int) Math.floor(Math.random() * rbi.length)].split("");
                str[0] = Integer.parseInt(arr[0]);
                str[1] = Integer.parseInt(arr[1]);
                pos = 2;

                while (pos < len - 1) {
                    str[pos++] = (int) (Math.floor(Math.random() * 10) % 10);
                }

                len_offset = (len + 1) % 2;
                for (pos = 0; pos < len - 1; pos++) {

                    if (((pos + len_offset) % 2)==0) {
                        t = str[pos] * 2;
                        if (t > 9) {
                            t -= 9;
                        }
                        sum += t;
                    }
                    else {
                        sum += str[pos];
                    }
                }
                final_digit = (10 - (sum % 10)) % 10;
                str[len - 1] = final_digit;

                String s = "";
                for(int i=0;i<str.length;i++){
                    s += str[i];
                }
                System.out.println(s.substring(0, len));
        }
    }
```

Using ScriptEngine the output is correct, but using Java only the last digit is not getting the correct value.

Please check this url to verify ,you will get an idea on what was the error: 
http://imei-number.com/imei-validation-check/

Comment: have you debugged your java code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want to take a look at this implementation of the Luhn algorithm in Java:

```
public class luhn {
    /**
    Calculate the Luhn sum of the input number
    @param str number to check
    @return sum calcuted with Luhn algorithm
    **/
    public static int luhnTest(String str){
        int sum=0;
        boolean isEven=false;
        for (int i=str.length();i>0;i--){
            int k=Integer.parseInt(str.substring(i-1,i));
            if(isEven){
                k=k*2;
                if(k/10!=0)
                    k=k/10+k%10;
            }

            isEven=!isEven;
            sum+=k;
        }
        return sum;
    }

    /**
    Return true if the input number is valid according to the Luhn formula
    @param str number to check
    **/
    public static boolean isLuhnValid(String str){
        if (luhnTest(str)%10==0)
            return true;
        return false;   
    }

    /**
    Return the check digit that makes the input number valid according to the Luhn formula
    @param str number to check
    @return calculated check digit
    **/
    public static int getCheckDigit(String str){
        int k=luhnTest(str+"0");
        int i=0;
        if(k%10!=0)
            i=10-k%10;
        return i;
    }

    /**
    Return the input number with check digit appended
    @param str number to make Luhn valid
    @return Luhn valid number
    **/
    public static String getLuhnNumber(String str){
        return str+getCheckDigit(str);
    }
}
```

Source: https://github.com/nicopi/Luhn-Algorithm